# How to password protect Icecast2 portal webpage

Tags: networking, security, passwords, raspberry-pi, icecast

I have a Raspberry Pi with a microphone attached, which is streaming audio. I have DDNS and port forwarding setup on the router, and so I can listen to the audio over the web.

Problem is, the Icecast2 webpage isn't password protected, which means anyone can listen to the audio if they know the IP / hostname and the port. When I setup this Icecast & Darkice setup ([link to the guide I used](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi-internet-radio-and-streaming-station)), Icecast asked for 3 passwords. But none of those are asked for when I open the portal webpage.

Is there any way to password protect the portal page shown below ?

[image]

This is the darkice config that I'm using:

```
[general]
duration     = 0     # duration of encoding, in seconds. 0 means forever
bufferSecs   = 5     # size of internal slip buffer, in seconds
reconnect    = yes   # reconnect to the server(s) if disconnected
[input]
device          = plughw:CARD=OSM09,DEV=0  # Soundcard device for the audio input
sampleRate      = 11025     # sample rate in Hz. try 11025, 22050 or 44100
bitsPerSample   = 16        # bits per sample. try 16
channel         = 1         # channels. 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
[icecast2-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr       # average bit rate
format          = mp3       # format of the stream: ogg vorbis
bitrate         = 320       # bitrate of the stream sent to the server
server          = localhost # host name of the server
port            = 8000      # port of the IceCast2 server, usually 8000
password        = --------- # source password to the IceCast2 server
mountPoint      = Stream.mp3  # mount point of this stream on the IceCast2 server
name            =  Raspberry Pi Stream # name of the stream
description     = Broadcast from Raspberry Pi # description of the stream
public          = no       advertise this stream?
```